# What's wrong with UserForm.Caption?

Tags: vba, userform, caption

Can someone experienced with VBA coding please explain this madness!

```
Dim thisForm As MSForms.UserForm

Set thisForm = ACADProject.FormENU 
'FormENU is user form I have, with some controls in it, 
'with a little piece of data in the caption so that it's visible
'when the form is shown

'When I do this
Debug.Print thisForm.Caption
'I get ""

'When I do this
Debug.Print thisForm.Controls(1).Parent.Caption
'I get the actual caption of the Form
```

Why does thisForm not know its caption before I ask it to one of its controls?
I'm executing this from a command button in the form that calls a procedure nested in a module

Comment: are you sure this is vba, which is used by excel, word, and other office products, instead of VB.net which is used in visual studio?

Comment: Possibly not but one can reproduce similar behaviour in Excel.

Comment: This happens because of the `Dim thisForm As MSForms.UserForm`, and is fixed by `Dim thisForm As ACADProject.FormENU`, but I'm not sure why. The [implicit form instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6049062/11683) does not appear to be the culprit, as the same behaviour reproduces with the proper `Set thisForm = New ACADProject.FormENU`.

Comment: No, this happens because of `Dim thisForm As MSForms.UserForm`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between declaring a userform as Object vs MSForms.Userform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408483/difference-between-declaring-a-userform-as-object-vs-msforms-userform)

Comment: @Storax It is related, but I wouldn't call it a duplicate. Here we have different observable behaviour when using `UserForm.Caption` and `UserForm1.Caption` off the same actual Form instance. Both have `Caption` in their intellisense.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, this is VBA.

Comment: Fyi Though another context as in your highly instructive analysis +:) of mapped child class properties, the following post might contribute to a certain understanding as it regards the *project references'* **sort order**:  [Dynamically add option button to userform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57910215/vba-dynamically-add-option-button-to-userform/57910553#57910553). @GSerg

Answer (score 4):

It would appear that this is due to a bug where the base class'es property is not properly mapped to the child class property!

`ACADProject.FormENU` inherits from `MSForms.UserForm`. It has much more properties and methods than `MSForms.UserForm`, but it [*is a*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44390954/11683) `MSForms.UserForm`, hence it can be stored in a variable of type `MSForms.UserForm`.

It would appear that internally `MSForms.UserForm` and its subclasses (the actual user forms designed by users) are implemented as different objects where the properties of the base dummy object return whatever the properties of the actual derived object return (which makes it look more of a *has-a* from the link above than of an *is-a*).
And it would appear that whoever mapped all the properties of `MSForms.UserForm` to return the respective values of the actual subclass, forgot to map the `Caption` property:

```vb
Dim FormAsSelf As UserForm1
Dim FormAsForm As MSForms.UserForm
Dim FormAsObject As Object

Set FormAsSelf = New UserForm1
Set FormAsForm = FormAsSelf
Set FormAsObject = FormAsSelf

Debug.Print "Caption from self: ", FormAsSelf.Caption, TypeName(FormAsSelf), ObjPtr(FormAsSelf), TypeOf FormAsSelf Is UserForm1
Debug.Print "Caption from form: ", FormAsForm.Caption, TypeName(FormAsForm), ObjPtr(FormAsForm), TypeOf FormAsForm Is UserForm1
Debug.Print "Caption from object: ", FormAsObject.Caption, TypeName(FormAsObject), ObjPtr(FormAsObject), TypeOf FormAsObject Is UserForm1

Unload FormAsSelf
```

| Title | Caption | Type name | Object address | Is a `UserForm`? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Caption from self: | UserForm1 | UserForm1 | 4144272 | True |
| Caption from form: |  | UserForm1 | 96261568 | True |
| Caption from object: | UserForm1 | UserForm1 | 4144272 | True |

The other properties appear to be mapped correctly, so if you design a form with a pink background and request `.BackColor` instead of `.Caption` in the code above, you will get the same answer from all three (actually two) "sides" of the form:

| Title | BackColor | Type name | Object address | Is a `UserForm`? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Caption from self: | 16744703 | UserForm1 | 4144272 | True |
| Caption from form: | 16744703 | UserForm1 | 96261568 | True |
| Caption from object: | 16744703 | UserForm1 | 4144272 | True |

---

As noted [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408483/difference-between-declaring-a-userform-as-object-vs-msforms-userform#comment41466507_26408483) under a related question, this entire inheritance situation is similar to the relationships between `Sheet1` and `Worksheet`. Those, however, appear to be implemented differently internally, so there is only one "side" to begin with:

```vb
Dim SheetAsSelf As Sheet1
Dim SheetAsSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SheetAsObject As Object

Set SheetAsSelf = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set SheetAsSheet = SheetAsSelf
Set SheetAsObject = SheetAsSelf

Debug.Print "Caption from self: ", SheetAsSelf.Name, TypeName(SheetAsSelf), ObjPtr(SheetAsSelf), TypeOf SheetAsSelf Is Sheet1
Debug.Print "Caption from sheet: ", SheetAsSheet.Name, TypeName(SheetAsSheet), ObjPtr(SheetAsSheet), TypeOf SheetAsSheet Is Sheet1
Debug.Print "Caption from object: ", SheetAsObject.Name, TypeName(SheetAsObject), ObjPtr(SheetAsObject), TypeOf SheetAsObject Is Sheet1
```

| Title | Name | Type name | Object address | Is a `Sheet1`? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Caption from self: | Sheet1 | Worksheet | 463669552 | True |
| Caption from sheet: | Sheet1 | Worksheet | 463669552 | True |
| Caption from object: | Sheet1 | Worksheet | 463669552 | True |

(Although, if you dig deep enough, you will find that Worksheets are into even [crazier shenanigans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36495738/11683)!)